# In which talk/scripture Swami Vivekananda tells to keep telling yourself that you are Brahman?

Tags: vivekananda

I can’t really remember. But I read somewhere where he says to keep telling yourself “Aham Brahmasmi”....and other mahavakyas until it becomes the living reality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many such quotes of Swami Vivekananda which have that purport. Here are only a few of those:

> You are the incarnations of the Almighty, Omnipresent, divine principle
>   (VIII.37)
>
> You are all God. (II.237)
>
> You are the Self, the God of the universe. (II.236)
>
> You are the almighty God of the universe. (II.236)
>
> We are God Himself though we have forgotten our own nature in thinking
>   of ourselves as little men. (III.160)
>
> You are God and so am I; who obeys whom? (II.320)
>
> You are the Self, and that must be realized. (IV. 245)
>
> You are free, free, free! (VII.61)
>
> Therefore know that thou art He; thou art the God of this universe,
>   *Tat Tvam Asi* (that thou art). (II.236)
>
> Thou art Reality. (VIII.106)
>
> You are all infinite. (II.470)
>
> You are the Infinite. (II.462)

Here, the II.462 etc are indicating the locations of the corresponding sayings in his Complete Works.

I have collected all these sayings from the book "Pearls of Wisdom-Swami Vivekananda"; published by RKMIC, Calcutta.